# Excecuting multiple slash commands on postgres prompt

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.20
psql -U postgres -p portNumber -h remoteServerip dbName \\copy remotetable("id", "Name") TO 'D:\localdesktopfolder.dump'
```

i am able to switch to remote database. But unable to copy remote table data to local.I am executing above statements on pgsql.exe in my local.

Comment: Your example will not work at all. You need to use `-c` to pass a single command to `psql`. A **much** better solution is to put everything into a single SQL script and use `-f script.sql` as a parameter to `psql`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html, "\\" is a separator meta-command, you can run `\copy` inside `-c`, like `psql -c "\copy remotetable("id", "Name") TO 'D:\localdesktopfolder.dump'"`

Comment: Use [pipe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html): `(echo \dt & echo \dx) | psql`